# Manage sessions with Telegram TL

Tags: telegram

I want to do following:

1. List all sessions
2. Get date and time that each session sign-ined
3. Terminate unwanted sessions

I read [official](https://core.telegram.org/schema) telegram document and [this](https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/) unofficial, but I couldn't find anything. I looking for something like "getSessions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do these steps:

1. call the below api:
   account.getAuthorizations#e320c158 = account.Authorizations;
2. use date_created and date_active of the Authorization object. (#7bf2e6f6)
3. call the below api by providing your desired session's hash:

   account.resetAuthorization#df77f3bc hash:long = Bool;

you're done!